# Is it Possible to Set a Chatter External User for Lead Default Owner?

Tags: chatter, profile, leads, user, owner

In my case Lead is coming from external system and might be they don't have the Lead Owner column so, i would like to set Lead Owner which is "Chatter External User" as a Default Owner. (I tried to select it from User Lookup but not able to see there)

Is it Possible to Assign Chatter External User to Lead Default Owner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't make a "Chatter External User" as a Default Owner. Because "Chatter External User" don't have access of salesforce data.

But as a workaround you can make a text field and store the Id there and make a default owner to all external records. Using this way you can keep the track of which user own the record.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't possible. Chatter Free/External and Chatter Plus users cannot be lead owners. Here's a list of things that Chatter Plus users can do: http://na8.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_chatterplus_tipsheet.pdf (PDF)